# Hikari connection pool does not recover from sql error : current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: scala, hikaricp

I am using the below function to execute a transaction of the for `BEGIN; QUERY 1; QUERY 2; COMMIT`

```
  def transform(transformFile: String): Unit = {
    val db = PostgresqlHikari.db
    try {
      val dbConfig = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("db.dwh")
      val schema = dbConfig.getString("schema")
      logger.info("Set connection schema ----> " + schema)

      val query = Source.fromResource("transformation/" + transformFile + ".sql")
        .getLines().mkString(System.lineSeparator())
      val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = db.prepareStatement(query)
      preparedStatement.execute()
      //db.close()
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable ⇒
        {
          logger.error(s"Error while processing $transformFile. Detailed error log ---" + ex.toString)
          //db.close()
        }
    }
  }
```

When there is no sql error, it runs fine. But, if I encounter an error, the actor just stops processing. 
  The error that I continously get is :

```
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

If I restart the service, it again starts processing correctly until the next `query error` occurs.

I am using the Hikari connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actor uses the `db` connection to execute a transaction. Now, if there is a `sql` error, the connection should `rollback` the changes. There are only 2 path to end a `sql` transaction, either `commit` or `rollback`.

I added the `rollback` logic in my catch block and now the error is not occurring any longer:

```
  def transform(transformFile: String): Unit = {
    val db = PostgresqlHikari.db
    try {
      val dbConfig = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("db.dwh")
      val schema = dbConfig.getString("schema")
      logger.info("Set connection schema ----> " + schema)

      val query = Source.fromResource("transformation/" + transformFile + ".sql")
        .getLines().mkString(System.lineSeparator())
      val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = db.prepareStatement(query)
      preparedStatement.execute()
      //db.close()
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable ⇒
        {
          logger.error(s"Error while processing $transformFile. Detailed error log ---" + ex.toString)
          //db.close()
          val rollback: PreparedStatement = db.prepareStatement("rollback;")
          rollback.execute()
        }
    }
  }
```